# Unable to create an object of type 'dbcontext' NPGSQL + EF Core 7.0

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm trying create a code-first database with EF Core and NPGSQL for my project. When I'm doing my first migration I get this error:

> Unable to create an object of type 'dbcontext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

What can be the reason for this issue? Thanks in advance, I'm attaching my code!

`ApplicationDbContext`:

```
using System;
using Domain.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Domain
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> opt):
            base(opt)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            => optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost;Database=UDP_Client;Username=postgres;Password=9316");


        public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Server> Servers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "UDP_ClientConnection": "User ID=postgres;Password=9316;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=UDP_Client;Pooling=true;"
    }
  }
}
```

StartUp.cs

```
using Domain;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using UDPClientService;
using UDPServerService;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddHostedService<ClientService>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<ServerService>();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(
        builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("UDP_ClientConnection")
    )
);

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Did you read that link?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No link attached to the comment

Comment: `For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728`. Did you read that link?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, but I think I don't need IDesignTimeDbContextFactory, because I have only these two tables to be created.

Comment: Have you specified the startup project? How do you try to create the migration?

Comment: @GuruStron I tried with the console with dotnet ef migrations add "TestMigration" -p project -s startProject but again no luck with the EFCore. Also, I have created a Database inside Postgres and populated a Client table, so I can create some endpoint to hit within the controller and for example to see the count of the clients which are in the DB, but again no success without the migration. That is the problem in my opinion.